# How to execute avconv command using perl script in linux

Tags: linux, perl, avconv

I need to execute following command with given arguments using perl script

> avconv -threads 4 -ss 0.0 -i /path/to/movie.avi output.ts

How to execute this command using perl script in linux environment?

Comment: See e.g. http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=78523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `system` function. For more details see [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)